# Unpacking packed primitives (such as an enum) from NSArray or NSDictionary during fast enumeration

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsarray, nsdictionary, fast-enumeration

You can put primitives in an NSArray or NSDictionary by packing them with the @() syntax. For example:

```
typedef enum {
    MyEnumOne,
    MyEnumTwo
} MyEnum

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                             @(MyEnumOne) : @"one",
                             @(MyEnumTwo) : @"two"
                             };
```

But how do you then use this with fast enumeration? For example, something like:

```
for (MyEnum enum in dictionary) {
    ...
}
```

This results in the error `Selector element type 'MyEnum' is not a valid object`

Answer (score 1):

The `@()` syntax creates a **boxed** NSNumber. Therefore, when enumerating, access it as an NSNumber. To cast it back to an enum, first extract the integer value, then cast:

```
for (NSNumber *number in dictionary) {
    MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)[number intValue];
    ...
}
```